# conda env create from yml locks up

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, yaml, conda, anaconda3

In a simple test, I tried to create a basic Conda environment, export that environment to a YAML file, and re-create the environment from the YAML file on the exact same computing instance.
No matter what I try, the re-create step hangs up (fails) with no error message (timeout)

This is on an AWS EC2 Linux instance.

Command sequence as follows:

```bash
conda create -n myenv python=3.10.4  
conda activate myenv   
conda list     ## output is shown below
conda env export > newenv.yml   ## yml contents are shown below...so far so good
conda deactivate
conda env create -n newenv --f newenv.yml  ## this is where it hangs up/freezes
<output> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): -    
<output> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): - Killed   ## after about 5mins
```

I have also tried multiple variations where I remove myenv before trying to re-create it using the same name (myenv). Folder permissions to the `anaconda3/envs` folder are `775` and there is no problem creating the environment. I have already updated, cleaned, and re-initialized Conda and have re-booted my instance multiple times.

Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated. This is my first Python project.

### Conda list output

```bash
(myenv) [ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-141 ~]$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/myenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.9.24            ha878542_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.39                 hcc3a1bd_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h58526e2_2    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.40.0               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.2.0              h46fd767_19    conda-forge
libuuid                   1.41.5               h5eee18b_0
libzlib                   1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h27087fc_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1s               h0b41bf4_1    conda-forge
pip                       22.3.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.10.4               h12debd9_0
readline                  8.1.2                h0f457ee_0    conda-forge
setuptools                65.5.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.40.0               h4ff8645_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2022g                h191b570_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.38.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
```

### YAML file output

```yaml
name: myenv
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=conda_forge
  - _openmp_mutex=4.5=2_gnu
  - bzip2=1.0.8=h7f98852_4
  - ca-certificates=2022.9.24=ha878542_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.39=hcc3a1bd_1
  - libffi=3.3=h58526e2_2
  - libgcc-ng=12.2.0=h65d4601_19
  - libgomp=12.2.0=h65d4601_19
  - libsqlite=3.40.0=h753d276_0
  - libstdcxx-ng=12.2.0=h46fd767_19
  - libuuid=1.41.5=h5eee18b_0
  - libzlib=1.2.13=h166bdaf_4
  - ncurses=6.3=h27087fc_1
  - openssl=1.1.1s=h0b41bf4_1
  - pip=22.3.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - python=3.10.4=h12debd9_0
  - readline=8.1.2=h0f457ee_0
  - setuptools=65.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - sqlite=3.40.0=h4ff8645_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h27826a3_0
  - tzdata=2022g=h191b570_0
  - wheel=0.38.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - xz=5.2.6=h166bdaf_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h166bdaf_4
prefix: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/myenv
```

Comment: I did mean conda env create .... I made a mistake when I typed in the question and have corrected that in the preceding text. Thanks for catching that detail! Still can't get anything to work and it is driving me crazy.

Comment: What does `conda config --show channel_priority` show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a memory issue (as in, lack thereof). I was trying to do this on an AWS EC2 instance that was on the t2.micro free tier. This instance only had 1GB of memory (RAM) and buried in the feedback I got from the dmesg command (run from the terminal after the command failed) I noticed an "Out of Memory" line. I increased the instance size and the problem went away. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Possibly a channel mixing issue.** I see `python` and `libuuid` come from **defaults** (i.e., **main**, **anaconda**) channel, whereas everything else is Conda Forge. If you have `channel_priority: strict`, then any packages in **conda-forge** channel (which is given priority by the YAML because it is first), will mask any packages of the same name in the lower priority channel (**defaults**).

Concretely, Conda is told to find `python` with a specific build (`h12debd9_0`) that is only available on **defaults**, but because **conda-forge** has `python` packages available, only those will be considered. The hanging is probably just Conda trying to "explain" why it can't find a solution.

#### Immediate Workaround

If this is the issue, then changing the channel priority to `flexible` should get it working.

```bash
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
```

#### Better: Avoid mixing channels

If you instead started from **conda-forge** to begin with, then everything should be fine. Conda Forge is entirely self-sufficient these days. Whereas Anaconda users often need to use Conda Forge packages to fill in the gaps. This practice (which is encouraged by Anaconda documentation with little warning about how problematic it is) generates a substantial portion of user issues.

Personally, I recommend a base install of [Mambaforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#mambaforge). It puts **conda-forge** as the default, installs a minimum of packages in the base environment, and comes with Mamba for fast environment solving.

Comment: This is a very helpful comment. Thank you! I am new to python and your comments helped expand my understanding. I did not try this, however, because I just found and tested a solution 20mins ago that I am posting now